# Access external CSS using javascript

Tags: javascript, css, canvas

JS:

```
var layer1 = document.getElementById('layer1');
ctx1 = layer1.getContext('2d'); 
layer1.style.zIndex=z1; //it is not working in my case
```

CSS:

```
canvas#layer1 { 
z-index: 3;}
```

How to access to this external CSS, and change value of z-index.

---

My mistake:

layer1.style.zIndex=cellValue; //not layer1.style.zIndex=z1; :)

Comment: just change the value of `layer1.style.zIndex`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
document.getElementById("layer1").style.zIndex = 3;
```

**Note**: You've to use CamelCase style in JavaScript when you have to deal with properties which are divided with `-`

Comment: I think you mean `zIndex` :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var canvas=document.getElementById('layer1');
canvas.styles.zIndex=anyIntegerValue
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a generic way to just inject CSS rules without fixating on targeting them in references. Works for all browsers.

```
function css_add_inline( css_code ) {
    var div = document.createElement( "div" );
    div.innerHTML = "<p>x</p><style>" + css_code + "</style>";
    document.body.appendChild(div.childNodes[1]);
}

css_add_inline( "#layer1 { z-index: 3 !important }" );
```

See this thing in action: http://pp19dd.com/2012/01/add-inline-css-or-remote-css-file-with-javascript/